# Добавить наложение для UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol

Я пытаюсь создать свой `UserControl` в C#, Состоящий из квадратов, нарисованных м методе `OnPaint`. Требуется добавить возможность накладывать такие контролы друг на друга и они не перекрывали друг друга. Прозрачный фон не помог. Пробовал это реализовать через `Region.Union`, пока не помогло.

Вот кусок с контрола:

```cs
namespace Union_Control
{
    public partial class Union_control_test : UserControl
    {
        public Union_control_test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            Region reg = new Region(new Rectangle(20, 20, 40, 40));
            reg.Union(new Rectangle(5, 5, 40, 40));
            pevent.Graphics.Clip = reg;
            pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, pevent.ClipRectangle);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Область отрисовки контрола перекрывает другой такойже контрол]

Comment: На самом деле лучше потратить время на то, что бы изучать WPF (где это делается за секунды времени) чем на то, что бы изучать как писать кастомные контролы под технологию которую оставили чисто для того, что бы писать тестовый интерфейс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не рисуйте квадраты, а вырежьте регион из контрола.
Для этого задайте созданный регион свойству `Region`.

```
public class CustomControl : UserControl
{
    public CustomControl()
    {
        Region reg = new Region(new Rectangle(20, 20, 40, 40));
        reg.Union(new Rectangle(5, 5, 40, 40));
        this.Region = reg;
        //BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема именно в том чтобы объединять регионы из разных контролов на главной форме.

Comment: Передача региона помогла, но потребовалось еще сделать контролы публичными, возможно не самый правильный способ, но сработало.